# Retrieving tweet by tweet-id by node.js

Tags: node.js, tweets

I'm trying to get contents of tweets by their identifiers using Node.js. But execution ends up with the following error:

> Error: connect ENCONNREFUSED 10.10.34.34:443"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: var TwitterPackage = require('twitter');
var secret = {
  consumer_key: '  ',
  consumer_secret: '  ',
  access_token_key: '  ',
  access_token_secret: '  '
}
var Twitter = new TwitterPackage(secret);
Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '#fire'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    console.log(tweet.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});